# Aislar el código HTML de un javascript

Tags: javascript, phonegap, framework7

Estoy usando `PhoneGap` con `Framework7` para hacer una aplicación hibrida.
Dentro de la carpeta con los archivos Javascript tengo mucho código en `HTML` y me gustaria aislarlo, por ejemplo este es una trozo de mi `pintarElementosEnpantalla.js`

```
function pintarElementoMaestro (resultado){
var html = '';
            html = html + '<ul>';
            $('#'+elementoLista).html("");

            for (var i = 0; i < resultado.rows.length; i++) {
                var item = resultado.rows.item(i);
                html = html + 
                    '<li>' +
                    '<div class="content-box">'+
                    '<div class="row" style="margin:auto 2%; border-bottom:1px solid #D4DCE1;">'+
                    '<div class="col-50">'+
                    '<div class="texto-nombre-trabajador">' + item.name + '</div>'+
                    '<div class="texto-numero-trabajador">' + item.code + '</div>'+
                    '</div>' +
                    '<div class="col-20">'+
                        '<div class="texto-horas-actividad">3:50</div>'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '<div class="col-30">'+
                        '<div class="texto-horas-parte">3:50</div>'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '</div >'+
                    '</div >'+
                    '</li>';

            }
            html = html + '</ul>';
            $('#' + elementoLista).html(html);}
```

Toda la parte de las etiquetas de `HTML` me gustaria tenerlo en otro archivo, para tener mas claro el código algo tipo asi:

```
function pintarElementoMaestro (resultado){
    var html = '';
                html = html + '<ul>';
                $('#'+elementoLista).html("");

                for (var i = 0; i < resultado.rows.length; i++) {
                    var item = resultado.rows.item(i);
                    html = html + HTML_GUARDADO_DE_OTRO_SITIO;//el HTML 
                   //esta en otro documento , me refiero a las etiquetas//'<li>' +
                //'<div class="content-box">'+ .....

                }
                html = html + '</ul>';
                $('#' + elementoLista).html(html);}
```

Alguna idea de como hacerlo?, he probado hacerlo como una variable en otro .js pero no funciona

Comment: Podrías utilizas ECMAScript 6, existe un feature de `import` e `export` o buscar algún plugin que simule este feature  para ECMAScript 5